# Class A loads and holds Class B, want to call method from Class B

Tags: php, oop

Haven't been able to quite find what I'm looking for, despite many questions with similar topics...

Example:

```
class A {
    public $_Thing_B; // class B object
}

class B {
    public function printSelf() {}
}
```

When constructed, `Class A` pulls a corresponding version of `Class B` into itself, and this object is used for a variety of private methods within `Class A`.

But `Class B` does have a few public methods that would still be useful when only "handling" `Class A` in the code (so not working directly with a standalone instance of `Class B`).

Thus, occasionally I'd like to do this:

```
$objA = new A;
$result = $objA->$_Thing_B->printSelf();
```

and it appears to me the only way to maintain this functionality is by declaring `Class B` to be a public variable inside `Class A`.

Is this correct? Or is there a way to keep it private whilst still exposing certain public methods?

Comment: Doesn't inheritance make more sense in this case?

Comment: Agree with NullUserException. This type of solution will cause problems for you in the future.

Comment: @NullUserException - I'm not sure, it's a backpack/book/page count issue, if that makes things more clear.

Comment: It's impossible to know if exposing object B as you are doing is better or worse than inheritance or adapters or traits, etc without knowing more about what those objects are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep `$_Thing_B` private in `A`, you could wrap the `B` methods you will need exposed in public methods.  I think this is odd though, and would personally just keep `$_Thing_B` as a public property, and access its methods directly as `A->B->method()`

```
class A {
    private $_Thing_B; // class B object is private

    // Wrap private _Thing_B's methods in public methods: 
    public function print_B() {
      $this->_Thing_B->printSelf();
    }
}

$objA = new A();
$result = $objA->print_B();
```

Answer (score 0):

For the special methods that you need to use ClassB for you can just create that method

so instead of

```
$objA->$_Thing_B->printSelf();
```

you call

```
$objA->printSelf();
```

and class A looks like:

```
class A {
    private $_Thing_B; // class B object

   public function printSelf(){
      $this->_Thing_B->printSelf();
   } 
}
```

Don't forget to instantiate class B e.g. inside the constructor but before you use it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for the class B object `$_Thing_B`, by re-implementing some of the Class B methods into Class A.

For instance, for the `printSelf()` method, we can use:

```
class A {
    private $_Thing_B;

    public function printSelf() {
        return $this->_Thing_B->printSelf();
    }
}

$objA = new A();
$result = $objA->printSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
$a = new A();
$a->_Thing_B->printSelf();

class A {
    public $_Thing_B; // class B object

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_Thing_B = new B();
    }
}

class B {
    public function printSelf() 
    {
        print_r("This is Class B::printSelf()");
    }
}
```

But you could also do this, which is probably the better way:-

```
$a = new A();
$a->getThingB()->printSelf();

class A {
    private $_Thing_B; // class B object

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->_Thing_B = new B();
    }

    public function getThingB()
    {
        return $this->_Thing_B;
    }
}

class B {
    public function printSelf() 
    {
        print_r("This is Class B::printSelf()");
    }
}
```

Both options give the output `"This is Class B::printSelf()"`

So, the `private` variable `$_Thing_B` is exposed by the `public` method `getThingB()`.